# SQL Query - Selecting certain rows from a table

Tags: t-sql

This is an example of what I want to do:

I have a table called: `TEST` it has two columns: `ColA` and `ColB`

It has the following data:

```
ColA  ColB
----  ----
0     1
0     1
0     3
2     1
2     3
```

I want to retrieve all values where ColA > 0, except I want to still include rows where ColA = 0 if ColB = 3

Comment: If you are getting started with SQL, there are some introductory tutorials here: http://sqlzoo.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should work:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     TEST
WHERE    ColA > 0 --All rows where ColA > 0
OR       (ColA = 0 AND ColB = 3) -- All rows where ColA = 0 AND ColB = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This SQL

```
SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE ColA > 0 OR ( ColA = 0 AND ColB = 3)
```

It returns the following data

```
ColA    ColB
0   3
2   1
2   3
```

Hope it  helps.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE colA > 0 OR (colA=0 AND colB=3);

Not test yet, but hopefully this should work.